# Permitir que um script acesse uma planilha google e retorne um JSON sem autenticação

Tags: json, google, script

Estava pensando em usar uma planilha do google docs como persistência de uma aplicaçãozinha que eu vou desenvolver.

Para tal, fiz o seguinte script no editor de scripts do google

```
function doGet(e) {
    var dados = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_DA_MINHA_SHEET).getSheetByName("Tabela 1").getDataRange();
    var res = {'Data': dados.getCell(1, 1).getValue()};
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(res));
}
```

Ja defini minha spreadsheet com visibilidade publica, pra que não se fosse preciso pedir permissões pra acessa-la.

Executando no navegador e logado na minha conta, o script funciona perfeitamente, retorna o json e tudo mais.

Porem quando nao estou logado, ela sempre pede autenticaçao, mesmo que funcione ao se logar com outra conta.

Como fazer ele exibir diretamente sem ter que passar por essa etapa?

Comment: Não sei eu entendi, o script em si pede autenticação quando você tenta executá-lo sem estar logado? Você saberia dizer qual chamada de método está disparando esse pedido de autenticação, se é o próprio `openById` ou se é em outro lugar? (P.S. você sabia que dá pra configurar um arquivo no Google Docs pra só quem tem o link consiga acessar - seja pra leitura ou leitura/escrita? É uma opção preferível a deixá-lo público, pois isso deixa claro que a intenção é não ter esse link divulgado).

Comment: É, em tese o Google mudou as coisas em 2013, de modo que mesmo pessoas sem conta possam ver um documento compartilhado, desde que tenham o link. Antes disso elas precisavam logar com alguma conta, qualquer que fosse. A seguinte planilha eu compartilhei num artigo para fins de ilustração e testei que abre mesmo sem fazer login, tente aí: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fDs2bCb9YYF4m9xbu2zojCipxOoijK58EpBac_WC6go/edit#gid=0

Comment: Esse link deve ajudar ------: http://blog.concretesolutions.com.br/2014/07/como-usar-uma-planilha-como-backend-json/